# Pagination & Categories (Incorrect URL Generated)

Tags: channel-entries, categories, pagination

I have a very standard news feature on the site i'm working on which has both categories and pagination for the entries. A problem i'm having is that the pagination is not filtering by category in the link it is generating.

When I am on a category URL (i.e. /news/category/general) this is not included in the {pagination_url} tag, meaning when you click it goes to the non categorised second page. The link I would expect is /news/category/general/P5 and I'm getting /news/P5

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Here is a shortened version of the tags:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" orderby="date" sort="desc" paginate_base="news" paginate="bottom" limit="5"}

    CONTENT

    {paginate}
        {pagination_links}
            <ul id="pagination">
                {first_page}<li><a href="{pagination_url}">&larr; First</a></li>{/first_page}
                {previous_page}
                    <li><a href="{pagination_url}">&larr;</a></li>
                    <li class="disabled">&hellip;</li>
                {/previous_page}
                {page}<li{if current_page} class="active"{/if}><a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>{/page}
                {next_page}
                    <li class="disabled">&hellip;</li>
                    <li><a href="{pagination_url}">&rarr;</a></li>
                {/next_page}
                {last_page}<li><a href="{pagination_url}">Last &rarr;</a></li>{/last_page}
            </ul>
        {/pagination_links}
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, you cannot have pagination_base set if you want it to include /category/general/ in the URL, it skips these otherwise.